# Facing an issue while selecting drop down in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

I am trying to select a drop down using selenium web driver, using this code:

```
WebElement admissionSource = driver.findElement(By.name("ABC"));
Select admissionSource_select= new Select(admissionSource);
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Here, `ABC` is the value name attribute for that element.

It is selecting as expected, however once it moves to the next drop down just below that, it deselects the previous one.

Things I've tried:

1) After filling the next drop down, going back and filling the previous drop down again. However this second attempt selects the first drop down but deselects the next drop down(as is the application). Filling the next drop down again throws below exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid
```

2) `Thread.sleep()`

3) Implicit wait

4) Explicit wait

Please suggest on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was coming because the in the 2nd dropdown, the options were dependent on the first one. So earlier i was just waiting for the dropdown box to get loaded. However in this scenario, even though the dropdown box had loaded but the dropdown options had not yet loaded for the 2nd drop down. Hence it was giving StaleElement Exception.
The way to tackle this is to use FluentDriver wait on the any (random) dropdown option and once it is loaded then only proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementException occurs when your referenced element is no more available or the element/page is refreshed. In your case, selecting from first dropdown refreshes/reloads your second dropdown. Hence, the StaleElementException occurs. To overcome this, after selecting from first dropdown, get the location of the second dropdown  and select your element afresh each time.

Comment: i am trying to find and select the second drop down element afresh each time. The only thing is, when i go for finding the second element (in the second attempt) , it gives StaleException for that element. @optimist_creeper

Answer (score 0):

Between these two sentences from your question:

```
Select admissionSource_select= new Select(admissionSource);
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Won't you need to do something like:

```
admissionSource_select.selectByVisibleText("Abc");
```

Where Abc is the name visible for that element.
You have just declared the drop-down element to be an instance of Select class. Is merely that sufficient? May be actually selecting the element was missing when you tried. You can try with adding above statement and then waiting while 2nd drop-down populates.

Comment: In my snippet here, I did not add that line(but in my actual code i had added that). However as I mentioned earlier, the issue was that the options had not loaded by the time I was searching for them. So the fix was to use fluent driver wait for the option to be selected.

Comment: Great! Thanks for clarifying. Glad it is sorted. :)